# How to get substring date (year) using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I've been doing this, is it possible to get the middle string in datetime.

Example :

Basically my string return this '12/23/2015 12:00:00 AM'.

However, what i want is actually '15' from the year 2015.

I've been using something like this 'strDate = strDate.Substring(0, 9)',

which sometimes return me wrong when the date is something like this '1/2/2015 12:00:00 AM'

Can someone help me on this, i am not sure if we can get the middle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use string methods for this, use `DateTime.TryParseExact`:

```
Dim str = "12/23/2015 12:00:00 AM"
Dim dt As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
    Dim yearOnly As String = dt.ToString("yy") ' 15
End If
```

**Update**: with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and this format you don't even need to use `TryParseExact`, you can use `Parse`/`TryParse` immediately:

```
DateTime.TryParse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
```

**MSDN**: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings, The "yy" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx#yySpecifier)

Comment: it works, i have try different approach too. i never really know about the tryparseexact before..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to treat it as just strings, you can get it by splitting twice.  First on the space, then on the slashes:

```
Dim justDate as String = strDate.Split(" ")(0)   'contains "12/23/2015"
Dim justYear as String = justDate.Split("/")(2)  'contains "2015"
Dim partYear as String = justYear.Substring(2,2) 'contains "15"
```

or all in one line:

```
Dim partYear as String = strDate.Split(" ")(0).Split("/")(2).Substring(2,2)
```

Comment: You do not need `strDate.Split(" ")(0)`, `Dim partYear as String = strDate.Split("/")(2).Substring(2,2)` is sufficient.

Comment: @abto Yes that's true.  I think I was thinking at the time that I was going to make it handle two digit years too - in which case you would need the first one, but then not the second, as you'd want to take the last two characters of the first string from `strDate.split`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    dim dateStr as string
    dateStr = "12/23/2015 12:00:00 AM"

    dim dateobj as new DateTime
    dateobj = DateTime.Parse(dateStr)

    dim year as integer
    year = dateobj.Year

    dim youWantStr = year.ToString().Substring(2)

    Console.WriteLine(youWantStr)
```